# I am trying to write a Python code that displays MCQ's from an Excel sheet into a HTML file

Tags: python, html, pandas, excel

I am facing error in the script part of the HTMl,

```
 <script>
            function calculateScore() {
                var questions = document.getElementsByClassName('question');
                var score = 0;
                var answer = '';

                for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
                    var options = questions[i].querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
                    var selectedOption = '';
                    var correctAnswer = questions[i].getAttribute('data-answer');

                    for (var j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
                        if (options[j].checked) {
                            selectedOption = options[j].value;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    answer += questions[i].getAttribute('data-id') + ': ';
                    answer += selectedOption === correctAnswer ? correctAnswer + ' (Correct)' : correctAnswer;
                    answer += '<br>';

                    if (selectedOption === correctAnswer) {
                        score++;
                    }
                }

                document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = answer;
                document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'Score: ' + score + ' out of ' + questions.length;
            }
        </script>
```

Whenever i run the code, it shows the correct answers as null and the answer count as 0 out of the number of questions i had in the sheet, irrespective of how many correct and incorrect answers i select in the HTML file.

Can you help me fix this?

Output should be:

```
1.____ (This answer is correct)
2.____ (This one is incorrect)
1 out of 2 correct
```

And I am getting:

```
null null
null null
0 out of 2 correct
```